# Is $f(x) = x^4 - 6x^2 + 3x + 57$ irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$ ? Over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I am wondering how to see whether or not $f(x) = x^4 - 6x^2 + 3x + 57$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ ,respectively.

One may start by finding a rational root. But the polynomial is $3$-Eisenstein, so it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

One can try to factor the polynomial by a quick-witted, algebraic trick, but I'm not seeing how one can do this with $f(x)$.

There is a formula for roots of a quartic polynomial, but it is very complicated, and hard to commit to memory.

Is there an easier way to see whether or not $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ ? I suspect it is irreducible over both, but how can I see this?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$x^4 + 1$ reducible over $\mathbb{R}$... is this possible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249143/x4-1-reducible-over-mathbbr-is-this-possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no and no.

Only polynomials of degree $1$ are irreducible over $\mathbb C$.

Only polynomials of degree $1$ or $2$ are irreducible over $\mathbb R$.

These statements are equivalent to the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: Which is why algebra in $\mathbb R$ is quite boring.

Comment: @DonThousand, this is not boring: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2101516/589